# "Your Podfile requires that the plugin `cocoapods-patch` be installed" after XCode 13 update

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

After getting a new M1 Macbook with MacOS Monterey 12.2.1 (21D62) and XCode Version 13.4.1 (13F100) when I run `cd ios` and `pod install` in a React Native project I'm getting:

> [!] Your Podfile requires that the plugin `cocoapods-patch` be installed. Please install it and try installation again.

I already searched for solutions.

Globally installing 'cocoapods-patch' doesn't make any difference.

There are no new updated for 'cocoapods-patch' since last year.

Apparently it's possible to force XCode 12 to work in Monterey and this should work, but it's not a proper solution. Eventually I will need to update to XCode 13.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Podfile:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/cocoapods.rb'

# source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'

platform :ios, '12.1.0'
plugin 'cocoapods-patch'

target 'MyProject' do
  use_unimodules!
  config = use_native_modules!
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
  pod 'GoogleToolboxForMac/NSString+HTML', '2.3.0'
  pod 'Mantle', '2.1.6'
  pod 'tealium-swift', '2.6.0' # all modules
  pod "tealium-react-native-swift", :path => '../node_modules/tealium-react-native/tealium-react-native-swift.podspec'

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => true
  )

  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
  pod 'Permission-AppTrackingTransparency', :path => "#{permissions_path}/AppTrackingTransparency"

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  # use_flipper!()

  #   post_install do |installer|
  #     react_native_post_install(installer)
  #   end
  # end
  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
    # Apple Silicon builds require a library path tweak for Swift library discovery or "symbol not found" for swift things
    installer.aggregate_targets.each do |aggregate_target| 
      aggregate_target.user_project.native_targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS'] = ['$(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/swift', '$(inherited)']
          config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
        end
      end
      aggregate_target.user_project.save
    end

    # Flipper requires a crude patch to bump up iOS deployment target, or "error: thread-local storage is not supported for the current target"
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
       end
    end

    # ...but if you bump iOS deployment target, Flipper barfs again "Time.h:52:17: error: typedef redefinition with different types"
    # We need to make one crude patch to RCT-Folly - set `__IPHONE_10_0` to our iOS target + 1
    # https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/834 - 84 comments and still going...
    `sed -i -e  $'s/__IPHONE_10_0/__IPHONE_12_0/' #{installer.sandbox.root}/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/Time.h`
  end
end
```

log after 'pod install --verbose':

```
Installing unimodules:
 expo-constants@11.0.2 from ../node_modules/expo-constants/ios
 expo-file-system@11.1.3 from ../node_modules/expo-file-system/ios
 expo-image-loader@2.2.0 from ../node_modules/expo-image-loader/ios
 expo-in-app-purchases@11.0.1 from ../node_modules/expo-in-app-purchases/ios
 expo-modules-core@0.2.0 from ../node_modules/expo-modules-core/ios
 unimodules-app-loader@2.2.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-app-loader/ios
 unimodules-core@7.1.2 from ../node_modules/@unimodules/core/ios
 unimodules-react-native-adapter@6.3.9 from ../node_modules/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/ios
 unimodules-task-manager-interface@6.2.0 from ../node_modules/unimodules-task-manager-interface/ios

  $ /Users/ramiro/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.0/bin/node -e try {console.log(require('@react-native-community/cli').bin);} catch (e)
  {console.log(require('react-native/cli').bin);}
  /Users/ramiro/mobile-darwin/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/bin.js
RNFBAnalytics: Using default Firebase/Analytics with Ad Ids. May require App Tracking Transparency. Not allowed for Kids apps.
RNFBAnalytics: You may set variable `$RNFirebaseAnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport=true` in Podfile to use analytics without ad ids.
Using firebase.json from '/Users/ramiro/mobile-darwin/firebase.json'
Adding a custom script phase for Pod RNFBApp: [RNFB] Core Configuration
Adding a custom script phase for Pod RNFBCrashlytics: [RNFB] Crashlytics Configuration
react-native-appsflyer: Using default AppsFlyerFramework.You may require App Tracking Transparency. Not allowed for Kids apps.
react-native-appsflyer: You may set variable `$RNAppsFlyerStrictMode=true` in Podfile to use strict mode for kids apps.
Auto-linking React Native modules for target `NewEspresso`: BVLinearGradient, RNBootSplash, RNCAsyncStorage, RNCMaskedView, RNColorMatrixImageFilters, RNDeviceInfo, RNFBAnalytics, RNFBApp, RNFBCrashlytics, RNFBFirestore, RNFBMessaging, RNFBPerf, RNFBRemoteConfig, RNFS, RNGestureHandler, RNKeychain, RNLocalize, RNPermissions, RNSVG, RNScreens, RNSentry, RNShare, RNSharedElement, RNVectorIcons, apptentive-react-native, react-native-ad-manager, react-native-appsflyer, react-native-background-downloader, react-native-background-timer, react-native-blur, react-native-mmkv-storage, react-native-netinfo, react-native-pager-view, react-native-photo-manipulator, react-native-safe-area-context, react-native-slider, react-native-track-player, react-native-view-shot, react-native-webview, and tealium-react-native
  Preparing
[!] Your Podfile requires that the plugin `cocoapods-patch` be installed. Please install it and try installation again.

/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:722:in `block in ensure_plugins_are_installed!'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:720:in `each'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:720:in `ensure_plugins_are_installed!'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:225:in `block in prepare'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:149:in `message'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:222:in `prepare'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:160:in `install!'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'

[!] use_native_modules! skipped the react-native dependency 'react-native-economist'. No podspec file was found.
    - Check to see if there is an updated version that contains the necessary podspec file
    - Contact the library maintainers or send them a PR to add a podspec. The react-native-webview podspec is a good example of a package.json driven podspec. See
    https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/react-native-webview.podspec
    - If necessary, you can disable autolinking for the dependency and link it manually. See
    https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md#how-can-i-disable-autolinking-for-unsupported-library
```

I want to add that when I do `pod`, I'm not getting the `patch` command, it's like cocoapods-patch wasn't installed at all. But I already did `sudo gem install cocoapods-patch` many times.

[image: pod commands available (patch is not here)]

Comment: Please share your podfile. Also have you tried [instructions](https://github.com/DoubleSymmetry/cocoapods-patch) for cocoapods-patch installation ?

Comment: Podfile was added to my question. Yes, the cocoapods-patch was already installed and working. It stopped working when started using XCode 13 (new Monterey Mac)

Comment: Maybe the problem is in some other place. Would you also share the complete installation error log/ stack trace ?

Comment: Just updated the post again.

Comment: Out of ideas at the moment. Maybe try ```pod update``` or ```pod install --repo-update```?
Will let you know if I think of anything else. ```plugin 'cocoapods-patch'``` seems to be working for us on xcode13.4.1

Comment: I'm thinking maybe it's related to my installation of cocoapods. I'm gonna try uninstalling it and reinstall. Maybe this plugin only works with a specific architecture? I don't know really.

Comment: It works for us on our mac-mini with new mac M1 architecture. You could try using [react-native-clean-project](https://github.com/pmadruga/react-native-clean-project) to do the uninstall/ cleanup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE 2023**

I bumped into this issue again and this time what worked for me was the other way around, uninstalling everything and installing with Gem.

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods cocoapods-patch

sudo brew uninstall cocoapods cocoapods-patch

sudo gem install cocoapods cocoapods-patch
```

**OLD**

The issue was fixed after following steps:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods cocoapods-patch

sudo brew uninstall cocoapods cocoapods-patch

sudo brew install cocoapods cocoapods-patch
```

Basically uninstalling everything and reinstalling with brew. It seems I had installed cocoapods with gem and cocoapods-patch with brew or the other way around.

Comment: I ran "brew install cocoapods cocoapods-patch", and got this: "No available formula with the name "cocoapods-patch". Did you mean cocoapods?"  This is on an M1 MacBook. Any idea why it didnt' work for me?

Comment: Reinstalling using brew could not find cocoapods-patch, instead reinstalling both with gem worked for me. 'sudo gem install cocoapods cocoapods-patch'

Comment: @7pixels have you found any solution? :|

Comment: Running command sudo brew uninstall cocoapods cocoapods-patch gives the following "Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.
As Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all
build scripts full access to your system."